# Two actions in with same action link in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have one problem. In my project i have one NEXT button. I when i click the next button i need to save all the records of page and also go to the next page at the same instance. Similar in next page also same process repeated. I have used single view and used the pagination.

I am little bit confused how to proceed. I have different Action result for Save and Next page.

SO any good way to move forward

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 2 action method which is save and next, why dont you call the Save action when the "NEXT" button is clicked, and then in your save action, just return the call to the Next action?

Hope I understand you right :)